# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 - Reset Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, reset

I was wondering if there is there a way to reset *ALL* Keyboard Shortcuts under System > Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard Shortcuts in Ubuntu Mate 16.04?

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

I've tried the following without success:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/
```

Answer (score 2):

In dconf Editor, you can see the schema `org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.media-keys`.

So, in terminal, you use following command:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
```

Screenshot of dconf Editor:
[image]